# What is this language?

Tags: turkic-languages, armenian, language-identification

[image]
This text was found in Bolu, Turkey, at my uncle's house. What language is it written in?

Comment: The alphabet is Armenian, but the text could be Armenian, Turkish, Kurdish or Kipchak.

Comment: @user6726 Turkish written in Armenian had umlauts.  There was not much if any Kurdish or Kipchak languages written in Armenian.  Anyway this example is Armenian.

Comment: A good method for lang id is stopwords.  In this case և, որ, մեր...

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer as of Kipchak you are wrong, there are some well known examples like https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#/media/File:Arm-100r.jpg

Comment: @shabunc Yes, and there are Kurmanji examples too.  But both are unlikely for something found in Bolu.

Answer (score 8):

I'm fairly sure that the language is Armenian. For example, the second word on the top line is միշտ (*mishd*) meaning "always", and the fourth line has the words քեզ (*kez*) "you" and մարդ (*mard*) "man".

I'm not fluent enough in Armenian to easily decipher the whole text, but the final line appears to read "January 1861".

Answer (score 2):

This is Armenian. I'm failing to translate whole text, though it's not a dialect, on the contrary, it seems to me to be a literary language, quite standard, it's just that I'm failing to understand 10% (or to read, some letters are unclear) of words, but this is 100% Armenian.

Some words I understand but never heard in that form (like "ջուրիկ խըմելու"). Still, it's Armenian.

Comment: Far western Armenian possibly? There were many dialects of West Armenian in Turkey before the Genocide

Comment: @Darkgamma written language != spoken language.  This is simply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Armenian_orthography.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer I understand that, but a written form of Western Armenian would fit the mark hypothetically. Orthography, after all, isn't the same as a written language, either